# Parsing data from the squished string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to write a pattern using Regex, which from the string `"PriitPann39712047623+372 5688736402-12-1998Oja 18-2,Pärnumaa,Are"` will return a first name, last name, id code, phone number, date of birth and address. There are no hard requirements beside that both the first and last names always begin with a capital letter, the id code always consists of 11 numbers, the phone number calling code is +372 and the phone number itself consists of 8 numbers, the date of birth has the format dd-mm-yyyy, and the address has no specific pattern.

That is, taking the example above, the result should be `[("Priit", "Pann", "39712047623", "+372 56887364", "02-12-1998", "Oja 18-2,Parnumaa,Are")]`. I got this pattern

`r"([1-9][0-9]{10})(\+\d{3}\s*\d{7,8})(\d{1,2}\ -\d{1,2}\-\d{1,4})"`

however it returns everything except first name, last name and address. For example, `^[^0-9]*` returns both the first and last name, however I don't understand how to make it return them separately. How can it be improved so that it also separately finds both the first and last name, as well as the address?

Comment: How would you address the problem if a name contains multiple words beginning with either upper or even lower case letters?

Comment: @lemon In my case, this is impossible. The first name always begins with one capital letter, just like the last name.

Comment: Given that assumption, try with the following one: `([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)([1-9][0-9]{10})(\+\d{3}\s?\d{7,8})(\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,4})([^,]+),([^,]+),([^\s]+)` >> https://regex101.com/r/OUEjhQ/2.

Comment: @lemon Thank you. But what if I needed to find only the first name from the entire string?

Comment: You're already extracting first name and last name separately. It's sufficient to not use Group 2.

Comment: @lemon I mean a separate pattern for finding exactly the name. Not using search and group.

Comment: If your name is found always in first position, it's sufficient for you to exploit that condition `^([A-Z][a-z]+)`

Comment: @lemon I see, but if I wanted only the last name in this case would it make sense to use a lookahead? Like here, It look ugly, but it works ([A-z][a-z]+)(?=[0-9]). Sorry if I'm asking trivial questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248815/discussion-between-lemon-and-qlimbo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex splits each of the fields into a separate group.

```
r"([A-Z]+[a-z]+)([A-Z]+[a-z]+)([0-9]*)(\+372 [0-9]{8,8})([0-9]{2,2}-[0-9]{2,2}-[0-9]{4,4})(.*$)"
```

You can get each group by calling

```
m = re.search(regex, search_string)
for i in range(num_fields):
    group_i = m.group(i)
```

Comment: You might want to adjust the `A-Z` and `a-z` to include special characters or umlauts.